# How to pass values to ViewModel using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, mvvm, model

I need to add data to view model using LINQ
My view model is :

```
public class SearchScrapViewModel 
{ 
public WClass wClass{get; set;} 
public SClass sClass{get; set;} 
public YClass yClass { get; set; } 
} 

public class WClass 
{ 
public string title { get; set; } 
public string link { get; set; } 
} 
public class SClass 
{ 
public string title { get; set; } 
public string link { get; set; } 
} 
public class YClass 
{ 
public string title { get; set; } 
public string link { get; set; } 
}
```

and i need to use these 3 classes with 3 different LINQ query and then pass data to `return View(SearchScrapViewModel);`

```
var wikians = //LINQ Logic 
select new SearchScrapViewModel 
{ 
wClass.link = link.Attributes["href"].Value, //Error: I am not able to add to wClass 
wClass.title = link.InnerText 
};
```

and similarly to other classes

and then pass to `return View(SearchScrapViewModel);` so that i can access all the 3 classes in View of this controller

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to *create an instance* of your WClass:

```
select new SearchScrapViewModel {
    wClass = new WClass { 
        link = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
        title = link.InnerText 
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could make WClass (and SClass and YClass) a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx) instead of a class, then you don't need to instantiate it. In that case, however, you should probably [make the struct immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

Comment: ok...i used this...but now how to pass... this to view... i mean using "return View(SearchScrapViewModel )" is not working...Do i need to do some change in viewmodel so that i can pass all class data to View using this main SearchScrapViewModel ?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not the be-all-end-all, and I dont know that this is the best approach for what you are looking for. I would suggest looking at the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), to accomplish this. If you really want to, you could do this in one LINQ query (using object initializers), but it might not read as clean as a builder would (but that is my two cents):

```
select new SearchScrapViewModel
{
    wClass = new wClass{title = xyz, link = xyz},
    sClass = new sClass...
    yClass = new yClass...
}
```

Comment: I used what @Heinzi suggest. but how to pass this to view... i mean using "return View(SearchScrapViewModel )" is not working...Do i need to do some change in viewmodel so that i can pass all class data to View using this main SearchScrapViewModel ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why you need a select statement in your example.  In any case you can't return SearchScrapViewModel as your return because that is a type and not the instance.  Unless your code is simplified for this post and you do need linq, I would suggest:

```
var wikians = 
new SearchScrapViewModel {
    wClass = new WClass { 
        link = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
        title = link.InnerText 
    }
}; 

return View(wikians);
```